# parsing through an extjs result

Tags: extjs

I am using the extjs file upload using ColdFusion as my server language. My ColdFusion uploadaction page is returning the following result to extjs.

```
{"success":true,"data":{"file":"img\/diamondring22.jpg","Contact Id":"contact1"}}
```

I am very new to javascript and I need to retrieve the value of the file.

I can display action.response.responseText and see the results. I need to see the results in action.results.data but is shows as a null.

I tried using `var mypluck = Ext.pluck('result', 'file');` but this returned nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the responseText and create a JavaScript object. Then you'll easily be able to access it's values.

```
var responseObj = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);

if (responseObj.success){
    var file = responseObj.data.file;
} else {
  //something
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I will try this out now.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and it did find file in the json string. It turns out Ext.decode is now used rather than Ext.JSON.decode. However, when showing the value of the file in my ext.messagebox alert it shows up as empty. So, ext is not finding the value. I checked my json string in jsonlint and it validated fine.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: are you using the alert correctly? the first parameter of the alert is the title of the message box, the second is the actual message